# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

2020-09-23T15:28:00.3483912Z java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
2020-09-23T15:28:00.3489821Z Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'salecChannelEventProcessor' defined in file [/home/runner/work/calculation-service/calculation-service/target/classes/com/demo/calculation/saleschannel/SalecChannelEventProcessor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.demo.json.schema.JsonValidator' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:

```
import de.demo.json.schema.JsonValidator;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {
        "com.demo",
        "de.demo" },
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter( Configuration.class )
        } )
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-context.xml")
@Import({SwaggerConfig.class, SalesChannelSqsConfig.class})
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
 @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean( name = "objectMapper" )
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper( JacksonService jacksonService ) {
        return jacksonService.getObjectMapper();
    }

@Bean(name = "jsonValidator")
    public JsonValidator jsonValidator() {
        return new JsonValidator();
    }
}

@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SalesChannelUpdateListerner {

  @NonNull
  private final SalesChannelService salesChannelService;

  @NonNull
  private final SalecChannelEventProcessor salecChannelEventProcessor;

  @SqsListener(value = "${sales.channel.update.queue.name}", deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
  @SneakyThrows
  public void receiveSalesChannelUpdateEvent(
      @NotificationMessage EnvelopedMessage envelopedMessage) {
    log.debug("Received message from sales channel update event queue : {}"
}


@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SalecChannelEventProcessor {

  private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE = "sales_channel_update";

  @NonNull
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
  @NonNull 
  private final JsonValidator jsonValidator;



  @SneakyThrows(JsonProcessingException.class)
  public boolean isValid(EnvelopedMessage envelopedMessage) {
    if (!MESSAGE_TYPE.equals(envelopedMessage.getType())) {
      return false;
    }
    return jsonValidator.validate(envelopedMessage);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `JsonValidator` bean. You need to change yor `SalecChannelEventProcessor` to be:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SalecChannelEventProcessor {

  private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE = "sales_channel_update";

  @NonNull
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Bean
  public JsonValidator  jsonValidator(){
       return new JsonValidator();
  }

  @SneakyThrows(JsonProcessingException.class)
  public boolean isValid(EnvelopedMessage envelopedMessage) {
      if (!MESSAGE_TYPE.equals(envelopedMessage.getType())) {
          return false;
      }
      return jsonValidator().validate(envelopedMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have defined the ```JsonValidator``` in ```SpringMvcConfig.java```

Comment: It's not the Bean that is being injected. You tried to inject the `de.demo.json.schema.JsonValidator`. If you already defined a JsonValidator bean in your config, make sure that its the same as the one that's imported in your `SalecChannelEventProcessor ` class